# flash progress bar in webpage? Using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

How to make progress bar in my page, that show how much flash file got progress in dwonload.

Comment: What language are you using on the server? You need server-side participation for a progress bar to work.

Comment: I'm looking for way using javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean just a normal flash preloader inside flash? There are loads of different tutorials on Google each showing you examples of how to do it in AS2 and AS3 with example code.

**AS2:**

http://the-dude.co.uk/tutorials/basic-flash-preloader-as2/

**AS3**

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/

Answer (score 0):

This [loading bar tutorial](http://flashexplained.com/preloaders/basic-loading-bar-preloader/) will get you started.